# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement CORSMiddleware (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for CORSMiddleware

Tags: middleware, fastapi

My pip3 version is 8.1.1, and python 3.6.
I want to know minimum which version is required to install CORSMiddleware?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to install CORSMiddleware, you do not need to install anything to activate CORS, it comes directly, just go ahead and import it.

```
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
```

For more details check the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/) out.

Comment: Then why still I am getting this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I am using python n react

Comment: did you add that middleware to the app with `app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware)` ?

Comment: yes

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=[origins],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

Comment: That usage is not correct, please follow the documentation